# Google maps info window button click jquery not working

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map integrated. It has a info window. The info window has button.
I also have a list with buttons that uses a jquery slider outside. Each button of this list has an on("click" event attached to it.

What I want is when the info window button from google map is clicked, I want the on("click") event to fire.

I have added a onclick="func1()" to the google map button.

In the function I have

```
 function func1(val){
    <id of list item>.on('click')
 }
```

But its not working.

I need some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var $selector = '.info-window-btn'; //class for your infobox buttons list
$(document).on('click', $selector, function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //your code
});
```

If it's work, you need to replace `document` to some `static` container which `closest` to map. For example you have this container for map:

```
<div id="gmap-container"></div>
```

So, you `$selector` will be `#gmap-container`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to remove the inline script:

```
<a id="btn">Button in GMap</a>
```

Then in your JS hanle your click:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('I'm clicked!');
});
```